# Python simple android notification

Tags: python, push-notification, android-notifications

Im looking for simple python push notification that trigger my android.

I expect a simple library like this

```
import notif
notif.auth(bla_bla_bla)
notif.send("this message is from python")
```

Im thinking about using telegram, since i saw it a bit complex so maybe there are another simple way.

Another support info: im gonna run it on my ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1):

Look into PushBullet, it's an app that runs on your phone that you can trigger with an API request.

https://docs.pushbullet.com/

After a quick look on google, I found this Github respository containing what looks like a library for sending notifications

https://github.com/rbrcsk/pushbullet.py

Using this, or something similar will solve your problem